# is it possible display multidemintional array in php using for loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional  array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ename] => willy 
            [due_date] => 12:04:2011
            [flag_code] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Father] => Thomas
            [due_date] => 13:04:2011
            [flag_code] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [charges] => $49.00

        )

)
```

i want to display values of array using php. but still fail. please any one help me to do this task....?

Comment: Must use a for loop. If it's homework just say so.

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($arrget_record); $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j<count($arrget_record[$i]); $j++)
 {
      echo $arrget_record[$i][$j];
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're so adamant that this be accomplished using only `for` loops, I have to assume this is a homework question. Because of this, I'll point you to several PHP manual pages in the hopes that you'll review them and try to learn something for yourself:

- [Arrays](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [For Loops](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)
- [Foreach Loops](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Now, I'm going to break your actual question a few different questions:

#### Is it possible to display a multidimensional array using `for` loops?

Yes. It's entirely possible to use a `for` loop to iterate over a multidimensional array. You simply have to nest `for` loops inside `for` loops. i.e. you create a `for` loop to iterate over the outer array, then inside that loop you use another `for` loop to iterate over the inner array.

#### How can I iterate over a multidimensional array using a `for` loop?

Generally, when you use a `for` loop, the loop will look something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $maxValue; $i++) {
  // do something with $1
}
```

While this works well for indexed arrays (i.e. arrays with numeric keys), so long as they have sequential keys (i.e. keys which use each integer in order. for example, an array with keys 0, 1, and 2 is sequential; an array with keys 0, 2, and 3 is not because it jumps over 1), this doesn't work well for associative arrays (i.e arrays with text as keys - for example, `$array = array("abc" = 123);`) because these arrays won't have keys with the numerical indexes your `for` loop will produce.

Instead, you need to get a bit creative.

One way that you could do this is to use `array_keys` to get an indexed array of the keys your other array uses. For example, look at this simple, one-dimensional array:

```
$dinner = array(
            "drink"     => "water",
            "meat"      => "chicken",
            "vegetable" => "corn"
          );
```

This array has three elements, each with an associative key. We can get an indexed array of its keys using `array_keys`:

$keys = array_keys($dinner);

This will return the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => drink
    [1] => meat
    [2] => vegetable
)
```

Now, we can iterate over the keys, and use their values to access the associative keys in the original array:

for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
  echo $dinner[$keys[$i]] . "
";
}

As we iterate over this loop, the index `$i` will be set to hold each index of the `$keys` array. The associated element of this key will be the name of a key in the `$dinner` array. We then use this key name to access the `$dinner` array elements in order.

Alternatively, you could use a combination of the `reset`, `current` and `next` functions to iterate over the values in the array, for example:

```
for($element = current($dinner); 
    current($dinner) !== false; 
    $element = next($dinner)
   ) {
  echo $element . "<br />";
}
```

In this loop, you initialize the `$element` variable to be the first element in the array using `reset`, which sets the array pointer to the first element, then returns that element. Next, we check the value of `current($dinner)` to ensure that there is a value to process. `current()` returns the value of the element the array pointer is currently set at, or `false` if there is no element there. Finally, at the end of the loop, we use `next` to set the array pointer ahead by one. `next` will return `false` when we try to read beyond the end of the array, but we ignore that and wait for `current` to notice that there is no current element to stop the loop.

---

Now, having written all of that, there *really* isn't any reason to do jump through all these hoops, since PHP has the built-in `foreach` construct which allows you to iterate over each of an arrays elements, regardless of key type:

```
foreach($dinner as $key => $value) {
  echo "The element in key '" . $key . "' is '" . $value ."'. <br />";
}
```

This is why I'm assuming this is a homework assignment, since you would probably never have reason to jump through these hoops in a production environment. It is, however, good to know that such constructs exist. For example, if you could use any loop *but* a `foreach`, then it would be a lot simpler to just use a `while` loop than to try to bash a `for` loop into doing what you want:

```
reset($dinner);
while (list($key, $value) = each($dinner)) {
    echo "The value of '" . $key . "' is '" . $value . "'.<br />";
}
```

---

In summary, to iterate over a multidimensional array with associative keys, you would need to nest loops inside each other as shown in the answer to the first question, using one of the loops shown in the answer to the second question to iterate over the associative key values. I'll leave the actual implementation as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

To print the values of a array, you can use the `print_r` function:

```
print_r($array);
```

This saves a for-loop.

Comment: by using for loop not for each... :( need to disply by using for loop

Answer (score 1):

Just use the handy function print_r

print_r($myarray);

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the print_r function, then for a true n-dimensional array solution:

```
function array_out($key, $value, $n) {
    // Optional Indentation
    for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
        echo("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
    if(!is_array($value)) {
      echo($key . " => " . $value . "<br/>");
    } else {
        echo($key . " => <br/>");
        foreach($value as $k => $v)
            array_out($k, $v, $n+1);
    }
}

array_out("MyArray", $myArray, 0);
```

Not sure if its possible to do with a `for` loop and mixed associative arrays, but `foreach` does work just fine.

Comment: it's entirely possible to loop over an associative array using a for loop (see my answer for examples), but it's annoying and there's really no reason to so long as foreach exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it with a for loop, you want the following:

```
$count = count($array)
for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    $count2=count($array[$i]);
    for($j = 0; $j <= $count2; $j++)
    {
        print $array[$i][$j] . "<br/>";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $array as $row ) {
    $values = array_values($row);
    foreach( $values as $v ) {
       echo "$v<br>";
    }
}
```

Should output:

```
willy 
12:04:2011
0
Thomas
13:04:2011
0
$49.00
```

Comment: by using for loop not for each... :(

Comment: @saint: Why does it have to be a `for` loop? This is exactly the sort of thing `foreach` was invented for.

Comment: Not hard to do. Just count the array indexes. $values is an indexed array as well. You can convert it. Try :)

Comment: Inner arrays hv associated value as keys... :(

Comment: @saint I don't even know what that means. array_values() returns just the values.

Answer (score 0):

This will actually be readable:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myCoolArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do it using something like assigning `array_keys` to an array, then using a for loop to go through that, etc...

But this is exactly why we have foreach - it would be quicker to write, read and run. Can you explain *why* it must be done with `for`?